# Where is the "content_my.xml" file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml

In the training [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html), it says that the *content_my.xml* should be in the *layout* directory. But as you can see in the picture below, it is missing from there. What can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably You have selected `EmptyActivity` instead of `BasicActivity` during creation of the project.
`Go to File -> New -> Activity -> Basic Activity` to create it in the same project or just start another project.

Comment: How? :)) "New to stack overflow"